# How to make $watch only trigger once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I added the `$watch`; the code inside the `$watch` throws an error if panodatas is `undefined`:

```
scope.$watch('panodatas', function(newVal) {
   if ('isCreate' in attrs) {
      $('.modal #points').hide()
      $('.modal #points-info').hide()
   }

   if (newVal || 'isCreate' in attrs) {
      scope.x = 0
      scope.y = 0
      scope.points = []
```

The problem is, the code fires every time `panodatas` changes.

How can I do it so that `$watch` only triggers once and not when `panodatas` changes in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scope.$watch`returns a deregister function, so if you do it like this:

```
var dereg = scope.$watch('panodatas', function(newVal) {
    dereg();
});
```

it will deregister as soon as it runs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var unwatch = $scope.$watch('someVar', function() {
   unwatch();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the `$watch` inside the function -

```
var listener = $scope.$watch("panodates", function () {
    // ...
    listener(); // Would clear the watch
});
```

It will be called once and then the watcher will be cleared.